# Vector space problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Do these sets make a vector space :

1) $$M_1 = \bigl\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2\mid 80996x + 40498y = 0\bigr\}$$
2) $$M_2 = \bigl\{F(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\mid\deg\bigl(F(x)\bigr) < 4; F(80996) = 0\bigr\}$$

Can you show me how to do these sort of exercises and if someone could also direct me to some literature and exercises of this kind I would be forever great full. I really want to learn how to do these problems on my self, but unfortunately I can't find the right stuff on the web.Again thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Have you tried checking all the axioms of a vector space? where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb Q^2$ and $\mathbb R[x]$ are both vector spaces, all that's left to answer is whether the sets you've defined are closed under addition and scalar multiplication.  Any subset of a vector space that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication is itself a vector space.  Another way of expressing "closed under addition and scalar multiplication" is "closed under linear combinations".  So is every sum of two members of $\bigl\{F(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]\mid\deg\bigl(F(x)\bigr) < 4; F(80996) = 0\bigr\}$ itself a member of that set?  Call those two members $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.  Both are polynomials of degree $<4$.  Is their sum a polynomial of degree $<4$?  Is every scalar multiple of $f(x)$ a polynomial of degree $<4$?  If $f(80996)=0$ and $g(80996)=0$, then is $(f+g)(80996)=0$?  If $f(80996)=0$, then is every scalar multiple of $f(x)$ evaluated at $80996$ equal to $0$?

For $M_1$, if the pair $(x_1,y_1)\in\mathbb Q^2$ satisfies $80996x + 40498y = 0$ and so does the pair $(x_2,y_2)$, then does the pair $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)$ satisfy that equation?  In *this* case, I'm guessing "scalar" would mean "rational number", so does $r(x_1,y_1)$ satisfy that equation whenever $r$ is rational?

Comment: Well I see what i have to do, but if you could write it down i would probably understand it better. I still don't get some of the stuff behind M2 and in M1 i guess i have to find two pairs that sued the equation and see if 80996(x1+x2) + 4098(y1+y2)=0.
Also if you could point me to some exercises of this kind that would be nice.

Comment: If $80996x_1+40498y_1=0$ and $80996x_2+40498y_2=0$ then $80996(x_1+x_2)+40498(y_1+y_2)=0$, so $(x_1,y_1)+(x_1,y_2)$ also satisfies the equation; thus is also a member of that set.  The set is therefore closed under addition.  If $80996x_1+40498y_1=0$ and $r$ is rational then it's easily seen that $80996(rx_1)+40498(ry_1)=0$, so $r(x_1,y_1)$ also satisfies the equation; thus is also a member of the set.  Therefore the set is closed under multiplication by rational numbers.  If it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication and is a subset of a vector space, then it's a vector space.

Comment: Thanks for that I got it. So for M2) the answer to  Is their sum a polynomial of degree <4? Is every scalar multiple of f(x) a polynomial of degree <4? is YES and also  (f+g)(80996)=0? is also yes because f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x) always but for tha scalar part i don't get it.

Comment: If $f(80996)=0$ then $3f(80996)=0$, and similarly for any other scalar besides $3$.